# Select-String cmdlet in PowerShell. Parsing parenthesis

Tags: powershell, select-string

I have this stored in a text file shown below:

```
Java 8 Update 111
Java 8 Update 111 (64-bit)
Java 8 Update 131
Java 8 Update 151
Java 8 Update 152
```

I am using PowerShell to do something with this information but struggling at the first hurdle. I am using `Select-String` to match a pattern and it isn't working.

```
Select-String "\\server\JavaVersions.txt" -Pattern "Java 8 Update 111 (64-bit)"
```

doesn't seem to work but the below brings back both.

```
Select-String "\\server\JavaVersions.txt" -Pattern "Java 8 Update 111"
```

Does anyone have any ideas why the one with the brackets in isn't working? Is it parsing issue? I really need to be able to get the `(64-bit)` one before the other one and act upon it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape special regex characters. In your case brackets.

```
Select-String '\\server\JavaVersions.txt' -pattern "Java 8 Update 111 \(64-bit\)"
```

https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, use `-SimpleMatch` to turn off regex matching:

```
Select-String '\\server\JavaVersions.txt' -Pattern 'Java 8 Update 111 (64-bit)' -SimpleMatch
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative option, if you don't need to use a regular expression for your match, you can use the `-SimpleMatch` parameter:

```
Select-String '\\server\JavaVersions.txt' -SimpleMatch "Java 8 Update 111 (64-bit)"
```

You then do not need to do any regex escaping.